# Switch Exisiting Repository To My Own Remote and GitHub Account

Tags: android, git, github

So I've done a repo sync from this: [GitHub](https://github.com/AOSPA/manifest). What that does is take all the repos in that organization that are in the manifest, and all the ones in other organizations that are in the manifest and download them to your computer. One of the repos in that link is called android_frameworks_base, which is the working_dir/frameworks/base folders when downloaded.

Now, what I want to do is switch over that android_frameworks_base repo to my own remote and account, and update the manifest to point to my remote, but I want to do it without forking. I also want to switch the branch to a different name.

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Perhaps fork it and modify as you wish.

Comment: @0andriy In my post I said I want to do it without forking. Second last line :)

Comment: I just don't want it to show forked or show the commits and stuff from people working on it from the original GitHub repo.

Comment: You can push branches of `android_frameworks_base` to your own repo. As to the manifest repository, you can also clone and push to another repo of yours. Modify `default.xml` where `remote`, `branch`, etc are defined. `default.xml` is used to download the newest code of defined branch of each repository. You can write other manifests according to your needs. Here's the format of manifest, https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/master/docs/manifest-format.txt

Answer (score 0):

Since you *don't want to show forked or show the commits of the original repo*, your only option is to create an entirely new repository.

To do this:

1. delete the `.git` folder in the *android_frameworks_base* repository
2. create a new repository with `git init`,
3. `add` everything and `commit`.

You can then create the branches with the name you like and push it to a new repo on github.

After point one, you can follow [this github guide](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/)